# How do I set the owner (or parent) of a Dialog Box?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2017

I have six windows that can all generate a dialog box. The dialog box needs to know which of the six windows generated it. I believe I should be able to call GetParent(hWnd), or GetWindow(hWnd, GW_OWNER) from within the dialog box, but both calls return the overall project window, instead of the third arg I passed into DialogBox().

Here's the code that generates the dialog box (all six windows share the same wndproc function), along with some printf debugging:

```
        case ID_SETTINGS_BUTTON:
            OutputDebugStringA("hWnd from Caller to DialogBox: ");
            char buffer[128];
            GetClassNameA(hWnd, buffer, 128);
            OutputDebugStringA(buffer);
            OutputDebugStringA("\n");
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_PORTSETTINGS), hWnd, portSettingsProc);
            break;
```

Here's the code at the beginning of the dialog box proc:

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK portSettingsProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (message) {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        for (int k = 0; k < PaneInfo::BAUDRATE_I_COUNT; k++)
            SendDlgItemMessage(hWnd, IDC_PORTSETTINGS_BAUDRATE, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)PaneInfo::BAUDRATE_NAME_ARR[k]);
        for (int k = 0; k < PaneInfo::DATABITS_I_COUNT; k++)
            SendDlgItemMessage(hWnd, IDC_PORTSETTINGS_DATABITS, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)PaneInfo::DATABITS_NAME_ARR[k]);
        for (int k = 0; k < PaneInfo::STOPBITS_I_COUNT; k++)
            SendDlgItemMessage(hWnd, IDC_PORTSETTINGS_STOPBITS, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)PaneInfo::STOPBITS_NAME_ARR[k]);
        for (int k = 0; k < PaneInfo::PARITY_I_COUNT; k++)
            SendDlgItemMessage(hWnd, IDC_PORTSETTINGS_PARITY, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)PaneInfo::PARITY_NAME_ARR[k]);
        OutputDebugStringA("GetParent(hWnd): ");
        char buffer[128];
        GetClassNameA(GetParent(hWnd), buffer, 128);
        OutputDebugStringA(buffer);
        OutputDebugStringA("\n");

        OutputDebugStringA("GetWindow(hWnd, GW_OWNER): ");
        GetClassNameA(GetWindow(hWnd, GW_OWNER), buffer, 128);
        OutputDebugStringA(buffer);
        OutputDebugStringA("\n");
        ...
```

And here's the code that defines the dialogbox:

```
IDD_PORTSETTINGS DIALOGEX DISCARDABLE 0, 0, 200, 200
STYLE DS_CENTER | DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION
CAPTION "Port Settings"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg"
BEGIN
LTEXT           "BaudRate:", IDC_STATIC, 10, 6, 100, 14
COMBOBOX        IDC_PORTSETTINGS_BAUDRATE, 10, 20, 180, 60, CBS_DROPDOWNLIST
LTEXT           "DataBits:", IDC_STATIC, 10, 40, 100, 14
COMBOBOX        IDC_PORTSETTINGS_DATABITS, 10, 54, 180, 60, CBS_DROPDOWNLIST
LTEXT           "StopBits:", IDC_STATIC, 10, 74, 100, 14
COMBOBOX        IDC_PORTSETTINGS_STOPBITS, 10, 88, 180, 60, CBS_DROPDOWNLIST
LTEXT           "Parity:", IDC_STATIC, 10, 108, 100, 14
COMBOBOX        IDC_PORTSETTINGS_PARITY, 10, 122, 180, 60, CBS_DROPDOWNLIST
DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK", IDOK, 80, 180, 50, 14
PUSHBUTTON      "Cancel", IDCANCEL, 140, 180, 50, 14
END
```

Here's the output from my printf statements:

```
hWnd from Caller to DialogBox: PaneClass
GetParent(hWnd): WINDOWSPROJECT2
GetWindow(hWnd, GW_OWNER): WINDOWSPROJECT2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> both calls return the overall project window, instead of the third arg I passed into DialogBox

The owner of a dialog box must be an overlapped or pop-up window. If OP's six windows are child windows, then the `hWnd` passed to `DialogBox` will be used to locate an eligible ancestor to use as an owner, instead, presumably the main window.

From the [Owned Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features?redirectedfrom=MSDN#window-relationships) documentation:

> *Only an overlapped or pop-up window can be an owner window; a child window cannot be an owner window. [...] The hwndParent parameter must identify an overlapped or pop-up window. If hwndParent identifies a child window, the system assigns ownership to the top-level parent window of the child window.*
>
> *Dialog boxes and message boxes are owned windows by default*

If the originator window that called `DialogBox` must be known to the dialog, then that information must be passed separately in some other way.

Comment: "*that information must be passed separately in some other way*" - like using `DialogBoxParam()` instead.  The desired info can be passed in the `dwInitParam` parameter, and will then be made available to the dialog in the `lParam` of the `WM_INITDIALOG` message.